# How to add button to this redirect page?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in js. It redirects all external links on my site to another waiting page then after 10 sec back to the main external link. the problem is that it does the redirection directly and I  don't want that. I want it to do the redirection to the external link after clicking on a button.
THIS IS AN EXAMPLE:https://androidmood-1.blogspot.com/2019/02/stormfall-saga-of-survival-v1112-mod.html

THIS IS THE WAITING PAGE WITH THE JS CODE:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ //add Font Awesome var cb = function() { var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet'; l.href = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css'; var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h); }; var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame; if (raf) raf(cb); else window.addEventListener('load', cb); //]]></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var seconds;
  var temp;
function removem1() {
    var xkl = getQueryVariable("url");
    var nkl=xkl.replace("&m=1", "");
document.getElementById("reload").innerHTML=nkl;
}
removem1();
document.getElementById('reload').href=window.location.href;
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("?&&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=_");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

  function countdown() {
    seconds = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
    seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10);

    if (seconds == 0) {
      temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
      parent.location.replace(document.getElementById("reload").innerHTML)
           return;
    }
    seconds--;
    temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
    temp.innerHTML = seconds;
    timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 3200);
  } 
setTimeout(function(){ countdown(); }, 1000);
</script>

</div>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
a#reload {display: none;}
#arabes1 {background: #ffa366;padding: 14px;font-size: 35px; font-Times: cursive;}
</style>
```

```html
<div dir="rtl" style="text-align: right;" trbidi="on">
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" trbidi="on">


Please Wait For Few Seconds. . . 

<div id="arabes1">You will be redirected to the link after <span id="countdown"> 10 </span> Seconds
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size: 45px;"></i>
<a id="reload" href="#"></a></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is redirecting you to the other page.

```
parent.location.replace(document.getElementById("reload").innerHTML)
           return;
```

remove it, instead you can show a button that when clicked redirects you.